# Java Equivalent to .NET's String.Format

Tags: c#, java, .net, string

Is there an equivalent to .NET's `String.Format` in Java?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have a look at the [String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [PrintStream.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) methods.

Both are based on the [java.util.Formatter class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

**String.format example:**

```
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(1995, MAY, 23);
String s = String.format("Duke's Birthday: %1$tm %1$te,%1$tY", c);
// -> s == "Duke's Birthday: May 23, 1995"
```

**System.out.format example:**

```
// Writes a formatted string to System.out.
System.out.format("Local time: %tT", Calendar.getInstance());
// -> "Local time: 13:34:18"
```

Answer (score 125):

The 10 cent answer to this is:

C#'s

```
String.Format("{0} -- {1} -- {2}", ob1, ob2, ob3)
```

is equivalent to Java's

```
String.format("%1$s -- %2$s -- %3$s", ob1, ob2, ob3)
```

Note the 1-based index, and the "s" means to convert to string using .toString().  There are many other conversions available and formatting options:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: I knew there was a reason I like C# much, much better! Maybe it's because C# is the first language I learned, but the Java version looks contrived.

Comment: The main reason C# looks cleaner is, it is newer language compared to Java. Syntactic sugar wasn't big those days (until Ruby came into prominence?).

Comment: It's prettier to concatenate the strings in Java, why did they make the syntax so complicated for such a commonly used function!

Answer (score 31):

There is `MessageFormat.format()` which uses the .net notation.

Comment: Just note that MessageFormat.format doesn't EXACTLY work the same, for example this: MessageFormat.format("<font color='{0}'>{1}</font>", "#112233", "Something") will return "<font color={0}>Something</font>". As you guessed, the problem is ' char - you rather need to supply: "<font color=\"{0}\">{1}</font>". Read for [MessageFormat class guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/MessageFormat.html) for more.

Answer (score 21):

You can also simply use `%s` for string, since the index is an optional argument.

```
String name = "Jon";
int age = 26;
String.format("%s is %s years old.", name, age);
```

The above example looks cleaner in my opinion.

A note about `%s` from the java documentation:

> If the argument arg is null, then the result is "null". If arg
> implements Formattable, then arg.formatTo is invoked. Otherwise, the
> result is obtained by invoking arg.toString().

Answer (score 7):

There is a [`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in Java, although the syntax is a little different from in .NET.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer to the OP's question, but may be helpful to others who are looking for a simple way of performing substitution of strings into a string containing C#-style "format items".

```
   /**
    * Method to "format" an array of objects as a single string, performing two possible kinds of
    * formatting:
    *
    * 1. If the first object in the array is a String, and depending on the number of objects in the
    *    array, then a very simplified and simple-minded C#-style formatting is done. Format items
    *    "{0}", "{1}", etc., are replaced by the corresponding following object, converted to string
    *    (of course). These format items must be as shown, with no fancy formatting tags, and only
    *    simple string substitution is done.
    *
    * 2. For the objects in the array that do not get processed by point 1 (perhaps all of them,
    *    perhaps none) they are converted to String and concatenated together with " - " in between.
    *
    * @param objectsToFormat  Number of objects in the array to process/format.
    * @param arrayOfObjects  Objects to be formatted, or at least the first objectsToFormat of them.
    * @return  Formatted string, as described above.
    */
   public static String formatArrayOfObjects(int objectsToFormat, Object... arrayOfObjects) {

      // Make a preliminary pass to avoid problems with nulls
      for (int i = 0; i < objectsToFormat; i++) {
         if (arrayOfObjects[i] == null) {
            arrayOfObjects[i] = "null";
         }
      }

      // If only one object, just return it as a string
      if (objectsToFormat == 1) {
         return arrayOfObjects[0].toString();
      }

      int nextObject = 0;
      StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      // If first object is a string it is necessary to (maybe) perform C#-style formatting
      if (arrayOfObjects[0] instanceof String) {
         String s = (String) arrayOfObjects[0];

         while (nextObject < objectsToFormat) {

            String formatItem = "{" + nextObject + "}";
            nextObject++;
            if (!s.contains(formatItem)) {
               break;
            }

            s = s.replace(formatItem, arrayOfObjects[nextObject].toString());
         }

         stringBuilder.append(s);
      }

      // Remaining objects (maybe all of them, maybe none) are concatenated together with " - "
      for (; nextObject < objectsToFormat; nextObject++) {
         if (nextObject > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(" - ");
         }
         stringBuilder.append(arrayOfObjects[nextObject].toString());
      }

      return stringBuilder.toString();
   }
```

(And in case you're curious, I'm using this code as part of a simple wrapper for the Android Log methods, to make it easier to log multiple things in a single log message.)