# Java: Does String.Format exist in Java like in C#?

Tags: java, c#-3.0

Something I discovered I like about C# are properties & String.Format.

Does something like String.Format from C# exist in Java?

C# ex:

```
int myNum = 2; 
int myNumSq = myNum * myNum;
String MyString = String.Format("Your lucky numbers are: {0}, & {1}", myNum, myNumSq);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Equivalent to .NET's String.Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754597/java-equivalent-to-nets-string-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It' even called [String.format()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
String myString = String.format("Your lucky numbers are: %d, & %d", myNum, myNumSq);
```

This method is available since Java 1.5.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, the class in question is "MessageFormat":

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

`MessageFormat.Format("Your lucky numbers are: {0}, & {1}", myNum, myNumSq);`

(Not sure if auto-boxing will work correctly in this case - you might need to convert the `int` to an `Integer` first)

Comment: Auto boxing works, its for precisely this use case it was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

```
String myString = String.format("Your lucky numbers are: %d, & %d", myNum, myNumSq);
```