# Does String.Format exist in Java like in C#? With the ability to recall variables?

Tags: java

I found this question answered but the problem is it does not address the functionality of {0} basically allows you to recall the same variable multiple times...

For example

in C#

```
String.format("Hello, {0} I heard you are {1} years old, {0} is a silly name", name, age);
```

Can this be duplicated in Java?

not really duplicate
[Java: Does String.Format exist in Java like in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482463/java-does-string-format-exist-in-java-like-in-c)

Comment: Why do you think this is no duplicate?

Comment: @isnot2bad because the Question he did post is about formating with parameter in generall, i guess he is asking about reusing the parameter name twice in format

edit: nvm the answer to his question is in an lower answer in the question

Comment: There's a way of formatting strings, if that's what you're asking.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, really, it  is a duplicate.  Read **all** of the answers, particularly the one that links to the javadocs for MessageFormat.  And read the javadoc itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
String name = "Steve";
String age = "200";

String formattedString = MessageFormat.format("Hello, {0} I heard you are {1} years old, {0} is a silly name", name, age);
System.out.println(formattedString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `String.format("%0$s %1$s %0$s", …)` and `MessageFormat.format("{0} {1} {0}", …);` work as you intend.