# String.Format (.NET) equivalent in Java?

Tags: java, android, string, equivalent, equivalence

The String.Format in .NET (maybe just VB.NET) convert {0}, {1}, ... into determined String, for example:

```
Dim St As String = "Test: {0}, {1}"
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(St, "Text1", "Text2"))
```

I've tried to search in both Google and StackOverflows, but they all return number-string format.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187676/java-equivalents-of-c-sharp-string-format-and-string-join?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Equivalent to .NET's String.Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754597/java-equivalent-to-nets-string-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The other suggestions are certainly good, but are more in the style of [`printf`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#1970s:_C.2C_Lisp) and its lineage which are more recent additions to Java. The code you posted looks to be inspired by [`MessageFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html).

```
String format = "Test: {0}, {1}"
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(format, "Text1", "Text2"))
```

I'm not really certain about what the `'Return:` statement is doing though.

Answer (score 6):

Use `MessageFormat.format`, you can also provide formatting arguments in the replacement tokens.

```
message = MessageFormat.format("This is a formatted percentage " +
                "{0,number,percent} and a string {1}", varNumber, varText);
        System.out.println(message);

message = MessageFormat.format("This is a formatted {0, number,#.##} " +
                "and {1, number,#.##} numbers", 25.7575, 75.2525);
        System.out.println(message);
```

Alternatively, `String.format` can be used but this doesn't guarantee position e.g. `String.format("What do you get if you multiply %d by %s?", varNumber, varText);`.

Comment: This answer is not complete. This is not the direct replacement. {0} and {1} in .NET are there so that they define the location of the parameters. For example it could be "Test: {1}, {0}", so %s, %s would replace wrong locations.

Answer (score 4):

```
String.format("Test: %s, %s",string1,string2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf()
System.out.format()
```

For other methods use:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Formatter f = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);
f.format("my %s", "string");
```

Comment: It looks a lot longer than spinning_plate's method, what is its difference?

Comment: It's the same result, although Formatter I believe can do a lot more but I would go with his method I just wanted to show some other ones in case you were doing different types of formatting.