# .NET String.Format equivalent in Java

Tags: java, .net, string-formatting, equivalent

I know there is a function `string.Format()` in .NET

Is there an equivalent version available in Java?

Comment: Did you search for this? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is also `String.format()` which supports output ala C `printf()` since Java 1.5.

```
String.format(String format, Object... args) 
System.out.format() // alternativ
System.out.printf() // alternativ
```

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String format = "Test: {0}, {1}"
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(format, "Text1", "Text2"))
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770126/string-format-net-equivalent-in-java) question and answers

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps not exactly equal but Java does have [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) which provides very similar functionality. You'll find that Java and C# are very similar.