# Java augment strings to string

Tags: java, string

I need to augment some string like it's done by logback/famous loggers or property accessors.

```
String str= "I can {0} give {1} back your horses or restore your {2} to life.";
String[] got=new String[]{"not","you","dead"};
```

Are they any utility functions provided by any library that can convert str to replace `{i}` with indices in array?

Its most probably a duplicate and please refer me to some similar question.

Comment: `MessageFormat` should be what you are looking for

Comment: You may implement one yourself using a matcher.  At each `{\d}` you may pause and append your replacement.

Comment: Check [Java Equivalent to .NET's String.Format  - 
MrSnowflake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10977910/4391450). It is exactly what you are looking for.